# sql: 3 Tables, joins, case, subselect?

Tags: t-sql

Normally pretty good at getting what I need, but this one has me stumped...  I'd like to get customer IDs back with accts matching criteria that have both prod a AND b matching my select statements below.  I can do joins and get customers with 1 or the other or both, but there has to be a better way!

3 tables
A=_Customer
Customer ID
Account_nbr
Product Code

b = product 1
b_sub product code
b_acct_nbr
b_status
b_balance

c=product_2
c_sub product code
c_acct_nbr
c_status

```
select
a.CustomerID
b.b_acct_nbr
b.b_acct_bal
b.b_acct_type
c.c_acct_nbr
c.c_acct_type

from a
where

Select a.customer_id, b.b_acct_type, b.b_acct_nbr, b.b_acct_bal
from a
inner join b
on a.account_nbr = b.b_acct_nbr
where b_acct_type = 01
and b_acct_bal > 700
and b_status = 1

SELECT a.customer_id, c_acct_type, c_acct_nbr
FROM c
inner join c
on a.account_nbr = c_acct_nbr
WHERE c_acct_type = 68
and c_status = 1
order by a.member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
Select a.customer_id, b.b_acct_type, b.b_acct_nbr, b.b_acct_bal, c_acct_type, c_acct_nbr
from a
inner join b
on a.account_nbr = b.b_acct_nbr
and b_acct_type = 01
and b_acct_bal > 700
and b_status = 1
inner join c
on a.account_nbr = c_acct_nbr
and c_acct_type = 68
and c_status = 1
order by a.member_id
```

We need some sample data for a more full answer!

Comment: Appreciate your effort, yes, I have run that exact script, and it doesn't return anything..  That is why I started looking at other ways to approach it, I thought the subselect might be an  option, but I'm rather new and need direction.  I'm sooo stuck!

Comment: I can run both queries independently, and get the results.